# How to detect if “/dev/mapper/dev0” exists in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to make a decryption software for my NAS, so that it automatically mounts all drives and decrypts them.

But, I need to know if the `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/blahblahblah dev0` exists after it had attempted to open it.

How do I detect that in Bash? I've attempted:

```
if [ -e /dev/mapper/dev0 ]; then
```

Then but that didn't seem to work. Anybody have any ideas?

---

This is the whole code:

```
fail="true"
LUKS_PASSWORD1=""
while [ $fail="true" ]; do
 echo -n " Password > "
 read LUKS_PASSWORD1
 echo "";

 for dev in "${!devs[@]}"; do
   echo "Opening ${devs[$dev]} to $dev"
   echo $LUKS_PASSWORD1 | sudo cryptsetup luksOpen $dev ${devs[$dev]} -d - &
 done;
 wait

 if [[ -e /dev/mapper/dev0 ]]; then
   [[ -e /dev/mapper/dev0 ]] && echo "true"
   ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/another-machine novum@10.147.20.100 -t 'play "/images/voices/Shuuten Douji/databasesunlocked.mp3"; wait; exit;';
   fail="false"
 else
   ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/another-machine novum@10.147.20.100 -t 'play "/images/voices/Shuuten Douji/that was incorrect, but please try again.mp3"; wait; exit;';
 fi
done
```

Comment: The answer to the tile is `[ -e /dev/mapper/dev0 ]` you have tried. `test -e /dev/mapper/dev0` is exactly equivalent. What do you mean by "that didn't seem to work"?

Comment: Even if it exists, the command returns false, for whatever the reason -- and I don't know why. It's nothing stupid (that I can think of) like case, or anything like that -- it's exactly written out the way the mapper file has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `test -e /dev/mapper/dev0 && run_some_command`

It would help if you show what came after the `then` and as to how it failed.

Comment: `test -e /dev/mapper/dev0` is exactly equivalent to `[ -e /dev/mapper/dev0 ]` the OP has tried. Any of them is the right command, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Unsure how to send my code, as, it was too long for in the message -- so imma send in a pastebin file; https://pastebin.com/qKq4gX9Q

Comment: And, to clarify, the SSH command basically just plays a noise on my main PC, of which is saying is the wrong one, and that it doesn't exist -- and doesn't escape the loop.

Comment: @NovumGain FYI `[ $fail="true" ]` tests if the *string* `value-of-fail=true` is not empty. It is always not empty, so the exit status will always be 0, unless the lack of quoting breaks the command. The command is very different than `[ "$fail" = "true" ]`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Duly noted -- I'll fix that rightaway, thank you. That said, it still plays the failing voice.. Implying that the if statement is the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @NovumGain You do not paste code "in the message". You paste code in the question. This time I did it for you.

Comment: Ah, okay. My bad. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

Strangely enough, everything started to work, even after 10 hours of bashing my head against a wall before, when I added a second bracket to the IF statement.. So yeah lol. Thank you everybody!

Comment: What is "a second bracket to the IF statement"? This answer is cryptic, I cannot imagine it will help any future user with a similar problem.